# Why does the "Programming Phoenix"-book add ".change1.ex" to files?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I keep seeing that the book refers to new files with ".change1." or ".change2." etc

So there is `ecto/listings/web/router.change1.ex`. Does it mean anything? Is it different from my other file `ecto/listings/web/router.ex`?

Comment: I believe, you should apply this changes subsequently to existing `router.ex`. This naming is done for reader’s convenience only.

Comment: @mudasobwa thank you! That was the case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of displaying the whole file eg. `router.ex` in Programming Phoenix you have following changes applied to that file. It's more concise and easier to grasp. Imagine that whole listings would be printed - it would be harder to find proper changes.